# 'Simple past' with unfinished period of time 'this week'

Tags: past-tense, time-words, time-reference

I've read that 'present perfect' is used with 'this week' mostly, as it's an unfinished time period. For example..

*I've had Chinese food this week.*

But if we add the adverb 'thrice' in the sentence, can we use 'simple past' here? Or adding 'thrice' wouldn't make any difference and it's correct to use 'present perfect'?

*I had Chinese food **thrice** this week.*

Comment: Nobody uses ***thrice*** any more. And note that the *only* good reason for using Present Perfect rather than Simple Past in you context (with or without "twice, three times,...") is if what you're saying has *particular relevance to time of speaking* - specifically, that would almost certainly steer you towards including the word ***already***, because you'd probably be saying something like ***I've had** Chinese food **three times** this week **already*** (so I want a change of diet - let's have fish and chips tonight instead).

Comment: _I've had_ is present perfect, not past perfect. And I partly agree with FumbleFingers that your first sentence is unlikely without some particular context. But I find nothing _I've had Chinese food three times this week_ quite natural, even without _already_.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, I understand..thanks for that. I just edited the question, it was 'present perfect' instead of 'past perfect'. So is it normal to write the sentence with 'simple past', and which word or phrase could be used in place of 'thrice'? Could you please rephrase the last sentence having 'simple past'?

Comment: @ColinFine: Fair enough - but I think if and when we find *I've had Chinese food three times this week* "perfectly natural", it's a context where the whole of ***this week*** represents the "current time of particular relevance". That's to say, if it's not about not wanting *another* Chinese meal, it's almost certainly going to be emphasising ***how  unusual this week is*** (because of that unusually high number of Chinese meals).

Comment: I already wrote the "preferred" Present Perfect version in my first comment. The Simple Past version is just *I had Chinese food three times this week*. As previously explained, ***already*** is only really likely with the Present Perfect version (implying / emphasising *...so I don't want it **again**!*).